# Ember-Data: finding records instead of promises

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection, callback, ember-data, promise

I'm trying to get the logged in user (from `/users?current=1` which works), and make that user available as a property throughout my application but rather than injecting my user I'm injecting this:

`Object { type: makeCtor/Class(), query: Object, content: Getter, store: Object, manager: Object, isLoaded: true, meta: Object, 3 more… }`

That, like totally, doesn't look like what I want. The record appears in the store just fine. Here is the relevant code. Thankyou for looking.

```
App.initializer({
    name: "appUser",
    after:['ember-data'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        var store = container.lookup('store:main');
        store.find('user',{current: "1"}).then(function(data){
            var user = data; //data.get('content')[0] (?) (Something else?)
            application.register("my:user", user, {instantiate:false});
            application.inject("controller", "user", "my:user");
            application.inject("route", "user", "my:user");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections have a property (`firstObject`) which will return the first item in the collection, or undefined.

You'll want to be careful with your thought around what the model should look like when you look at it in the console.  It hides the properties in sub properties, and returns them when you use getters and sets them when you use setters.  This is all for the ability to rollback.

```
App.initializer({
    name: "appUser",
    after:['ember-data'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        var store = container.lookup('store:main');
        store.find('user',{current: "1"}).then(function(data){
            var user = data.get('firstObject');  
            console.log(user.get('first_name')); // use getters to view the properties
            application.register("my:user", user, {instantiate:false});
            application.inject("controller", "user", "my:user");
            application.inject("route", "user", "my:user");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks kingpin, your really helping me get to grips with Ember. Your solution works.

Comment: Glad to hear, the learning curve is a tad monstrous, but once you get some of the basics, it becomes super cool.  Good luck!